# promise in loop in node.js

Tags: node.js, promise

```
Promise.all(function(){
    for(var numb in req.body){
        console.log(numb+":"+req.body[numb]);
        checkValue(numb,function(err,result){
            if(result){
                console.log(result);
                send[result]="true";
                console.log(send);
            }
            if(err){console.log(err+"not");}
        });
    }   
}).then(res.json(send));
```

I want to execute the for loop first and then send the data back. I am trying to use promise.all but I am not sure if its correct. could someone help me out?

Comment: Please format/indent  your code properly to make it readable.

Comment: You pass an array of promises to `Promise.all()`.  You do not pass a function to `Promise.all()`.  There are also no asynchronous operations in the code you show so there is no reason to use promises at all.  You can just code a regular loop.

Answer (score 33):

If you're using Promises, check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

you can just fix this by doing the following:

```
var promises = [];

for(var numb in req.body)
{
    promises.push(checkValue(numb));
}

Promise.all(promises)    
 .then(function(data){ /* do stuff when success */ })
 .catch(function(err){ /* error handling */ });

function checkValue(numb){
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  // place here your logic
  // return resolve([result object]) in case of success
  // return reject([error object]) in case of error
});
```

Comment: Great answer! Just for those of us who don't know Promise.all: if it fulfills it returns an array of the values from the fulfilled promises in the same order as defined in the iterable.